# How to return all records where Email Address on file is not Null?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

Need to pull all records that don't have an empty email addr column. What do I need to add to my SOQL below to make it valid?

Select email_addr, first_nm, last_nm, mbl_tel_nbr, city_nm, prov_cd, post_cd from [Customer_Profile_Data_to_SFMC]

Comment: Marketing Cloud uses SQL, not SOQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re running this in Marketing Cloud, it’s SQL, not SOQL.

And to find all records that have an email, you need to add a where clause at the end:

```
Select 
email_addr, 
first_nm, 
last_nm, 
mbl_tel_nbr, 
city_nm, 
prov_cd, 
post_cd 
from [Customer_Profile_Data_to_SFMC]
where email_addr is not null
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Comment: I did that and it still says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'.

Comment: email_addr is a text field if that means anything

Comment: What was the error message in your original query?

Comment: I found the error, which lied in another clause, thanks for your help!